# A question about complex polarization

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, sg.symplectic-geometry, quantum-mechanics

Let $M$ be a symplectic manifold, Then a subbundle $P\subset TM^{\mathbf{C}}$ of the complexified tangent bundle is called a complex polarization if

1. $P$ is Lagrangian
2. P involutive
3. dim$P\cap\bar P \cap TM$ is constant.

Let $P_1, P_2$ be two complex polarization, then when $\bar P_1\cap P_2$ is involutiove ?

Comment: Dear @Hassan Jolany, I cannot see how the tags 'quantum-mechanics', 'mp.mathematical-physics', and 'gt.geometric-topology' are relevant for your question. Are you sure they are required?

Comment: In fact this question come from Blattner–Kostant–Sternberg pairing in Geometric quantization. That is why , I added quantum mechanics. But I remove the tag of geometric topology

Comment: Yes, you right.My conjecture is if,$P_1,P_2$ be positive then $\bar P_1\cap P_2$ is involutive

Comment: Is Hassan Jolany no longer with us ? There are now two users $1234$, see http://mathoverflow.net/users/45187/1234 and http://mathoverflow.net/users/21574/1234.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be missing something, but isn't it completely obvious that $\bar P_1\cap P_2$ is always involutive?

Indeed, if $\xi$, $\eta$ are two complex vector fields taking values in $\bar P_1\cap P_2$, then $[\xi,\eta]$ takes its values in $\bar P_1$ because $\bar P_1$ is involutive, and in $P_2$ because $P_2$ is involutive, hence it takes values in $\bar P_1\cap P_2$, no?